Daisy chaining monitors to laptop and PC
I've two monitors:

Samsung Odyssey G5: HDMI and DP
Philips 273V7QJAB: HDMI, VGA and DP

I'm looking to create a setup where I'm able to have a two monitor setup for both my PC and laptop.

PC slots for HDMI x 1 and DP x 3
Laptop has HDMI and USB-C

My current setup is that I have both monitors linked into my desktop and the G5 linked to my work laptop, just a change of source on the G5 switch over.
However, life would be a lot easier with a two monitor setup on my laptop and ideally a setup with the fewest cables possible where the process of switching the inputs of switching inputs to the monitors isn't awkward and where the output from the laptop is just one cable.
My desk is a bit of a nest of cables as it is, it doesn't need to be any worse!
I've heard mention of an additional device (name escapes me atm) that I could plug the monitors into and from there link to at least one device.
However, I'm not sure how well that works when there's both a laptop and desktop.
